# Cannot change password from Oracle EM

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, password, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am facing an issue as follows:
I login to em using `SYS` as `SYSDBA`. Enterprise Manager shows information screen saying my password is going to expire. `SYS` Password will expire on 7th Feb 2017 as confirmed with Sql Plus:
[image: Sql plus windows]
Now on EM side, when I go to `preferences -> General -> Password` and try to change my password, it says `Current Password - Current password is invalid.`
[image: Password error]

I am providing same password I used to login to EM as `SYSDBA` but no luck.

Can someone advice what the problem is? How can I access database from EM in this situation. Also, please briefly advice about how to extend password expiry date.

DB Version: Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the best practice to use `SYS` user to use in Enterprise Manager. And you can change password for the user like `SYSTEM` or `SYSMAN` using OEM but not for `SYS` user.

You can change the password of `SYS` user using SQL*PLUS command called `password` which send the password in encrypted form instead of plain text.

```
[oracle@ora12c ~]$ sqlplus sys@oracdb as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Jan 24 13:37:49 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> password
Changing password for SYS
Old password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
Password changed
```

First of all find out which profile is assigned to the user-

```
SQL> select profile from dba_users where username='SYS';

PROFILE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT
```

-then you can user [ALTER PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2007.htm) to change password life time.

Also password doesn't cause effect on `SYS` user(I couldn't find documentation link) as demonstrated below.

```
SQL> alter user sys password expire;

User altered.
```

But I still can connect to the database using old password.

```
C:\Users\user>sqlplus sys/oracle@192.168.30.133:1522/oracdb as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Jan 24 13:52:46 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options
```

However, if your password for `sys` user has expired and unable to login then-

use [ORAPW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba007.htm#i1006814) utility

run `sqlplus / as sysdba` from the terminal of the user who owns the Oracle software.

Comment: Cool, let me try it. One thing more, I want to have a backup of this db. I assume I can take a backup using `EM` with `SYS` account. Can you suggest some good and to the point scenario to backup my db? Actually it is quite an important db and I don't want to lose anything using any hit and trial method.

Comment: If the database is important then you should have concept of how Oracle database backup and recovery works which can be learned from Oracle documentation. [RMAN Backup Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmcncpt.htm#BRADV002)